# $C_c(R^n)$ is not closed in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis

The closure of $C_c(R^n)$ in $L^{\infty}$ is $C_o(R^n)$ but why is not closed in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Because there are functions in $C_0$ that are not in $C_c.$ For example, $f(x)= 1/(1+|x|).$

Answer (score 1):

Consider any function $\phi \in C(\mathbb{R})$ having support in $[0,1]$, i.e. $supp(\phi)\subset [0,1]$.
Then the sequence $\{ \psi_n \} \subset C_c(\mathbb{R})$
$$
\psi_n=\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{-i}\phi(x+i)
$$
converges in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\psi=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 2^{-i} \phi(x+i) \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$, but it does not have compact support. 
This example can be generalized to higher dimensions in the same manner.

Comment: $C_0(R^n)$ and $C_b(R^n)$ are closed in $L^\infty$?